# Array Filter on DataStudio

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

Is there a way for DataStudio to filter out items inside an array aggregated row data (I used array_agg() method on Bigquery) The data has been generated from BigQuery.

Example:

| Date | keyword | product_array | sales_array |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| July 1, 2021 | query_1 | product A, product B, product C | $100,$200,$300 |
| July 2, 2021 | query_1 | product A, product B, product C,product D | $150,$250,$350,$400 |

I wanted to filter the row items by Date, keyword and Product Name.

**Example filter:**

*Date*    : July 1-2, 2021

*Keyword* : query_1

*Product* : Product A

**Result on datastudio:**

| keyword | product_array | sales_array |
| --- | --- | --- |
| query_1 | product A | $250 |

The filtered result will then show up the data including the sales values filtered by the Product Name.

Hope anyone could answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You apparently have two arrays that are "aligned".  To handle this, you can use `with offset` and join the unnested arrays:

```
select t.*, product, sales
from t cross join
     (unnest(t.product_array) product with offset pn join
      unnest(t.sales_array) sales with offset sn 
      on pn = sn
     )
where product = 'product A' and
      date in (date '2021-07-01',  date '2021-07-02') and
      keyword = 'query_1';
```